# How to log incoming request with Scala & Play Framework?

Tags: scala, playframework

Scala version is 2.13.8 and Play is 2.5.0 , I am getting `Http 414 URI Too Long` error and wanted to print that uri, how to manage that ?

Comment: Did you try with a "filter"?

Comment: You may also tune the Plas server config to allow for larger URLs. See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ProductionConfiguration

Comment: Last thing: Play 2.5 is quite old. I'd strongly encourage you to upgrade. 2.9 and 3.0 are out for a few months.